# Predict using psych in R for PCA

Tags: r, pca, psych

I have a data set which I divided into the training and testing set after first recoding qualitative variables to integers. I ran PCA analysis using the psych package.

For the training set, I ran the below code:

```
train.scale<-scale(trainagain[,-1:-2])
pcafit<-principal(train.scale,nfactors = 11, rotate="Varimax")
```

It extracted the components as below:

```
                       RC1  RC4  RC3  RC5  RC2  RC6  RC7  RC8  RC9 RC11 RC10
SS loadings           2.44 1.92 1.90 1.72 1.65 1.46 1.40 1.15 1.10 1.01 1.01
Proportion Var        0.10 0.08 0.08 0.07 0.07 0.06 0.06 0.05 0.05 0.04 0.04
Cumulative Var        0.10 0.18 0.26 0.33 0.40 0.46 0.52 0.57 0.61 0.66 0.70
Proportion Explained  0.15 0.11 0.11 0.10 0.10 0.09 0.08 0.07 0.07 0.06 0.06
Cumulative Proportion 0.15 0.26 0.37 0.48 0.58 0.66 0.75 0.81 0.88 0.94 1.00
```

For the test set, I ran the below code:

```
str(testagain)    
testagain.scores<-data.frame(predict(pcafit,testagain[,c(-1:-2)]))
```

The str(testagain) shows that my data structure is similar to trainagain, with all contents being integers. However, for the testagain.scores, the contents are all NaN.

How can I get "predict" to work? To my knowledge, I am following:

```
# S3 method for psych
predict(object, data,old.data,options=NULL,missing=FALSE,impute="none",...)
```

from:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/2.0.7/topics/predict.psych

Answer (score 0):

I think I might stumble across the solution:  to remove one of the features/columns whose data is exactly the same across all samples.